# How to identify cxf web service end point

Tags: web-services, cxf

I am trying to creating web service using wsdl first approach and CXF. I am able to generate java file from wsdl and deploy the war file to tomcat server. However, I don't see any soapaction in the generated file. How do I identify the end point url for this web service?

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Usually in CXF you use Spring configuration to configure endpoint, as described in [JAX-WS Configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html). Usually address is relative, e.g.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <jaxws:endpoint id="classImpl"
        implementor="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.service.Hello"
        address="/helloService"/>

</beans>
```

Address is local to you web app context root.

Assuming that name of you web application is `SomeWebApp` and the server is available at `localhost:8080` then web service should be published at `http://localhost:8080/SomeWebApp/helloService`. You can test it retrieving WSDL at: `http://localhost:8080/SomeWebApp/helloService?wsdl`. This URL can be used to create SOAP UI project (the tool that I really recommend for exploring and testing SOAP services).

If you don't use Spring to configure endpoint or you still can't access web service please provide more details about your configuration.